# How to remove newline in tabular addition

Tags: c

When executing this code, additions are separated by a newline each time I enter a value. So for example:

> ```
> 1
>
>      4     7      10
> ```

I reckon this is caused by the scanf() inputting a new line. How do you write the following code such that

```
  1    4     7     10
```

is printed?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;
    int counter = 1;
    printf("A\tA+3\tA+6\tA+9\n");
    scanf ("%d", &number);
    while (number != -1) {
        while (counter <=3) {
            number += 3;
            printf("\t%d", number);
            counter++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        scanf ("%d", &number);
        counter = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not *you* who enter a newline to end the input? That newline is going to be hard for your program to remove, since it's not actually printed by your program, but instead is handled by the terminal or console program. Instead I suggest a different strategy: Print the actual input as well as the normal input, all on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mixed the concept of input & output. Actually in your code, you had only output:

`>     4     7      10`

try replace this code with your inner while loop, then pipe the standard out to another file, check the results and you will understand.

```
while (counter <=4){
     printf("%d\t", number);
     number += 3;
     counter++;
}
```

`./your_program > output_file`